# Can't open "face_detector\deploy.prototxt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to learn python, for detect someone used mask or not.

when i run this code

```
prototxtPath = r"face_detector\deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = r"face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")

print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
```

i got error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13672/2145281415.py in <module>
     34 prototxtPath = r"face_detector\deploy.prototxt"
     35 weightsPath = r"face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
---> 36 faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)
     37 
     38 maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")

error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1126: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "face_detector\deploy.prototxt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile'
```

i tried searching on google with the same problem, and i got problem in certain file. My python project file is in **C:\Users\mfahm\anaconda3\Test**. Am I getting the wrong filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems. turns out you have to use / and not \ in your path.
so your code becomes like this

```
prototxtPath = "face_detector/deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = "face_detector/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")

print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
```

P.S i am using opencv 4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **.txt** in prototxtPath

```py
prototxtPath = r"C:\Users\DR\Downloads\face_detector\deploy.prototxt.txt" # <- different to other answer
weightsPath = r"C:\Users\DR\Downloads\face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the program cannot find the path to the model. One way to resolve this will be to provide the entire path with ("/") and another will be to find the relative path using the following command and then use that:

```
import os 
os.path.relpath("<path to the directory>/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is caffe model, try using: cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - Pulling my hair out convinced that the `deploy.prototxt` and `res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel` files were where in the wrong directory. However it wasn't them, it was actually `notebook` in the wrong directory.

Please check that too rather than wasting a couple of hours like I just did!

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue due to \ because initial I was running the project on Window that time It was working fine. Same project when I tried to run on Linux Mint, I got same error then after I changed to / because windows uses \ for directory while Linux uses /

Replace the below code:

```
prototxtPath = r"face_detector/deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = r"face_detector/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure that files `deploy.prototxt` and `res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel` are in the correct directory, then use `os.path.join`

```
import os

prototxtPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'face_detector', 'deploy.prototxt')
weightsPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'face_detector', 'res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel')

faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
```

Comment: relative paths are resolved relative to CWD anyway. getting CWD and gluing it on *makes no difference* that I can see. -- the only issue is that the files aren't where they're expected to be.